# using max() function XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a problem on how to use max() function on XPath,

If consider following xml, I need to select the `<tr>` element which has maximum number of child `<td>` in it.

```
<doc>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>aa</td>
                <td>bb</td>
                <td>cc</td>
                <td>dd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>nn</td>
                <td>oo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>qq</td>
                <td>rr</td>
                <td>ss</td>
                <td>tt</td>
                <td>uu</td>
                <td>vv</td>
                <td>xx</td>
                <td>yy</td>
                <td>zz</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</doc>
```

SO I wrote following xpath query

```
tr[max(count(child::td))]
```

But it return no result. can anyone suggest me a query that I can get `<tr>` which has maximum number of child `<td>`s ?

Comment: What should happen if multiple `tr`s have the same number of `td`s (and that is the maximum)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,  then the both <tr> should be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that this expression gives you what you want:

```
//tr[count(./td)>=count(following-sibling::tr/td) and
     count(./td)>=count(preceding-sibling::tr/td)]
```

That is, we want the count of the current nodes `td`s to be greater or equal to the count of any preceding node's `td`s and any following nodes `td`s.

You may want to adjust the starting point (I just went for any `tr` by starting with `//`) and depending on the relationships required, the `sibling` axes might need to be change to plain `following` and `preceding`.